# How Roolback and commit in spring mvc use JdbcTemplate

Tags: spring-mvc, jdbc, commit, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

How Roolback and commit in spring mvc use JdbcTemplate

jdbc.xml

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<beans:bean id="ds"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <beans:property name="url"
        value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:db12c" />
    <beans:property name="username" value="phutran" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="Phut0107" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="ds"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="ds"/>
</beans:bean>
```

who can help me, thank :(.

Answer (score 0):

JdbcTemplate doesn't handle transaction by itself. You should use @Transactional annotation in your code.

[Example](http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/spring-jdbc-transactions-example)